# I need to subtract Time From same column by applying filters on it

Tags: powerbi, dax, daxstudio

I have [scan Time] column and [Location] column which have different locations like Security T2, Post security T2 DOM , Post Security T2 INT.

So want to subtract Scan Time of Post security T2 DOM and Security T2 also Post security T2 INT and Security T2

So i have tried to make measure like this

Post_Security_T2_DOM - Security_T2 =
var Security_T2 =
CALCULATE(AVERAGEX(
FILTER(EGateData, EGateData[Location] = "Security-T2"),
(EGateData[Scan_Time])))

var Post_Security_T2_DOM =
CALCULATE(AVERAGEX(
FILTER(EGateData, EGateData[Location] = "Post Security T2 DOM"),
(EGateData[Scan_Time])))

var Total_Time =
CALCULATE(Post_Security_T2_DOM - Security_T2)

return
FORMAT(Total_Time,"HH:MM:SS")